# Is it possible for the range to have a bigger cardinality than the domain?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

My teacher just posed the following problem:

> "Given a function, explain why it's impossible for there to be more elements in its range than in its domain."

I immediately had an issue because of examples like $$f: (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbf{R}$$ $$x \mapsto \tan x$$

But I suppose, to a mathematician there *aren't* "more elements" in $\mathbf{R}$ than in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, as to a mathematician they have the same cardinality and hence have the same "amount of elements". Hence the following question came to mind:

> Is it possible for a *function's* range to have a bigger cardinality than its domain?

Comment: Your surmise is correct.  The cardinality of $(- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\Bbb R$ are the same.  As for your question, use the fact that functions are, by definition, single-valued.  See why the claim would be false for an arbitrary relation (that does not need to be single-valued).

Comment: Actually, you need the "Axiom of Choice" to prove that the range of a function can't have greater cardinality than its domain. For example, if $\mathbb R$ is the set of all real numbers, and $\Omega$ is the set of all "countable ordinals", then you can define a function mapping $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R\cup\Omega$, but without the Axiom of Choice you can't prove that $\mathbb R\cup\Omega$ doesn't have greater cardinality than $\mathbb R$. (By the way, in English we would say "number of elements" rather than "amount of elements.")

Comment: @RobertShore This is what I suppose my teacher was getting at. He is likely looking for an explanation like "If there were 'more elements' in the range than in the domain, then there would have to be at least one element in the domain that maps to two distinct elements under $f$; hence rendering it not a function."

Comment: @bof so your answer is no, it is not possible for a function to have a range whose cardinality is greater than its domain? As for your critique on my English, you're right "amount" shouldn't be used for plural count nouns such as "elements" (Perhaps, why I plan to major in math)

Comment: Well, the Axiom of Choice has been somewhat controversial. Early in the 20th century, some famous mathematicians (including Lebesgue if I remember right) considered it dubious or wrong. If you reject the Axiom of Choice, you can't rule out functions whose ranges have greater cardinality than their domains. Of course that can't happen in the "Real World."